# Convert Map<Integer, String> to Map<String, String>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert Map to Map

So far i tried below

```
Map<Integer, String> inMap = new HashMap();
        inMap.put(100, "Test1");
        inMap.put(101, "Test2");
        inMap.put(102, "Test3");
```

> How do i apply String.valueOf() on Entry::getKey?

```
    Map<String, String> collect = inMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));  //how to apply String.valueOf() on Entry::getKey
```

> This is working

```
    Map<String, String> map1 = inMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> String.valueOf(entry.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> b)); //Working
```

> why String.valueOf(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue() does not work even though its biFunctional?

```
    Map<String, String> map2 = inMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> String.valueOf(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue()));  //
```

Comment: Because it's parsed as `entry -> String.valueOf(entry.getKey())` and `entry.getValue()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `toString()` Because in all wrapper classes `toString()` is overridden to return value

```
 Map<String, String> collect = inMap.entrySet()
                                    .stream()
                                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry->entry.getKey().toString(), Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `entry.getValue()` is not a `Function` but `entry -> entry.getValue()` is.

```
Map<String, String> map = inMap.entrySet()
                               .stream()
                               .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> String.valueOf(entry.getKey()), entry -> entry.getValue()); // should work
```

Or you could simply use `forEach` as:

```
Map<String, String> outMap = new HashMap<>();
inMap.forEach((k, v) -> outMap.put(k.toString(), v));
```

Comment: `map2.put(k.toString(),v));` seems very much intuitive.